# Opencart: SEO URLs not working in the second store

Tags: .htaccess, opencart

My default store is `http://www.mydomain.com/store1`

My second store is `http://store2.mydomain.com`

In the .htaccess file, I have `RewriteBase /store1/`

In the Admin - `Catalog > Information`, the About Us page is set to appear in both stores.

This URL works fine: `http://www.mydomain.com/store1/about_us`

However this URL shows Internal Server Error: `http://store2.mydomain.com/about_us`

Is it happening because the default store is installed within a folder(`/store1/`) and not in the root? Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is caused by the `RewriteBase` being set. Simply remove the `RewriteBase /store1` line from your `.htaccess` file and that should fix it. Most sites will be able to guess the correct `RewriteBase` and so it's not necessary. If that doesn't work, you may want to try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045897/with-mod-rewrite-can-i-specify-a-rewritebase-within-a-rewritecond)