# Stop subdomain redirecting to main domain

Tags: html, .htaccess

When I search for the `subdomain.domain.es` I'm redirected to domain.es.
Code in htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://dominio.es/$1 [R=301,L]
```

My hosting company gave me the htaccess so my web was redirected from http to https but I have no clue of what any of this code means.
I'm new to web programming so I hope you can help.

Thanks so much!

Comment: have you seen the answer on this question? it looks like you might need to specify some values : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045897/with-mod-rewrite-can-i-specify-a-rewritebase-within-a-rewritecond

Answer (score 0):

This answer worked for me. I hope this can help someone else!

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]